# Safari not loading/playing webm audio

Tags: safari, webm

I have made a website that captures audio from the user, and saves it on a server. The audio recording process works in all browsers, but Safari can't play the audio that is saved on the server.

For example, this file: https://audio.joaqu.im/media/1682025718984.webm plays on Chrome but not Safari. Why is this?